# Unable to get my Docker image's base image

Tags: docker

I built a docker image with my on changes on top of a docker image from docker hub. Now I forgot the base image I used to build my image. Is it possible to find that?

I tried `inspect` and `history` but that did not give me the required information.

Comment: It's not easy. Did you try running `docker images` to list all available images?

Comment: hmm I could narrow it down to 2 images I have. I am sure one of them was the one.

Comment: Well you could compare the `docker image history your_image` with the history of both. You can also use [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to assist in analyzing.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious answer is to check your Dockerfile if you stil have it. 
`FROM base-image:tag`

Its probably not the case, so the best you can do is run
`docker images` - check when your image has been created and check all the images that were created before your image.